# EnumProperty property not found — why?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I'm new to Python and Blender scripting. I've been modifying an existing script, which worked up to a point, but after my modifications it started throwing an error:

```
rna_uiItemR: property not found: VIEW3D_PT_AlignUi.fruit
```

I've reduced it to this snippet, which still throws the error. Why?

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import (Panel)
from bpy.props import (EnumProperty)

class VIEW3D_PT_Test(Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_label = "Test script"
    bl_context = "objectmode"
    bl_category = 'Test'
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    
    fruit: EnumProperty(
        items=(("0", "Apples", "Apples"),
               ("1", "Oranges", "Oranges"),
               ("2", "Bananas", "Bananas")),
        name="Fruit",
        description="Choice of fruit"
        )

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(self, 'fruit', expand=True)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PT_Test)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PT_Test)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Panels can't own custom properties. You need to register it on an object like for instance the current scene. in `register` `bpy.types.Scene.my_enum = EnumProperty(...)` and in `draw` : `row.prop(context.scene, "my_enum")`

Comment: Thanks! I made your suggested changes and I was still getting the same error, but then I ran an unrelated script and suddenly my panel script kicked in. Weird, but successful.